# Create a new project with a specific version in VoltRb

Tags: ruby, version, voltrb

When I run `volt new foo`, it creates a project with the 0.9.3 version. I want to be able to create a new project with the `0.9.4pre1` version, but I'm not sure how to do that. How do you configure Volt so that running `volt new foo` will create a project with a specific version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the the pre release using

```
gem install volt --pre
```

for the latest pre release or

```
gem install volt -v 0.9.4pre1
```

for a specific version

Answer (score 1):

When volt runs it will always use the highest version installed on the machine.  (This is sort of a rubygems limitation).  So if you want a lower version, you have to remove the newer ones.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that. That is useful to know, thanks.